# Slow Selection Query even after indexing the table (sqlite and c++)

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

## Create tables

I have a database composed of two tables:

1. ENTITE_CANDIDATE
2. VARIATIONS

Tables are created by using the following queries:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENTITE_CANDIDATE (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, ID_KBP TEXT NOT NULL, wiki_title TEXT, type TEXT NOT NULL);"

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VARIATIONS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, ID_ENTITE INTEGER, NAME TEXT, TYPE TEXT, LANGUAGE TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(ID_ENTITE) REFERENCES ENTITE_CANDIDATE(ID));"
```

- Table ENTITE_CANDIDATE is composed of *818,742* records
- Table VARIATIONS  is composed of *154,716,653* records

---

## Index tables

I indexed the previous tables by using the following queries:

```
`CREATE INDEX var_id ON VARIATIONS (ID, ID_ENTITE, NAME);`
`CREATE INDEX entity_id ON ENTITE_CANDIDATE (ID, wiki_title);`
```

---

## Retrieve information

I want to retrieve from table **VARIATIONS** the following records:

```
"SELECT  ID, ID_ENTITE, NAME FROM VARIATIONS WHERE NAME=foo ;"
```

Every **select** query is taking around *5.414931* seconds. I know the table contains a very large number of records. But can I make the retrieval faster? Am I indexing correctly the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#where_clause) says:

> the index might be used if the initial columns of the index … appear in WHERE clause terms.

This query uses only the `NAME` column to search, so the `var_id` index cannot be used. (That index is useful only for lookups that use `ID`, which is mostly useless because the `ID` column is already indexed as PRIMARY KEY.)

Comment: OK @Cl. So i cannot use index in my case. And Can I use the index on foreign keys?

Comment: That depends on the query. The documentation explains when indexes are usable.

Comment: How do you think I can speed up the select query?

Comment: By reading the documentation. Then you know that you have to create an index whose initial column appears in the WHERE claus terms.